# SQLiteConstraintException:NOT NULL constraints android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a an Editor Activity where i insert my data in the database.

I've created 3 columns as :-

- **ID INTEGER**,
- **Task TEXT NOT NULL** and
- **Days TEXT**.

I insert data into the **Task** column with data from an edit text and insert other data into the **Days** column by creating an alert dialog containing an edit text.

I'm successfully able to insert data into the **Task** column but when i insert data from the alert dialog into the **Days** column, I get this error :-

> "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: Task.TaskName (code 1299)".

Please help me with this.I know there  are same question available but android studio doesn't help much in debugging the sq lite database and also the error are different for all,keeping in mind that please,please don't mark this question as duplicate.

**THIS IS MY SQLITE CREATION SYNTAX**

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String query= "CREATE TABLE " + ChallengesEntry.DB_TABLE  + " ("
                +ChallengesEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN + " TEXT , "
                +ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN_DAYS + " TEXT);";

        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

**THIS IS MY EDITOR ACTIVITY CLASS**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_save:
                insertTask();
                // Exit activity
                finish();
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:
                // Navigate back to parent activity (CatalogActivity)
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:

                final EditText editText =  new EditText(this);
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Add new Challenge")
                        .setMessage("Whats your Challenge")
                        .setView(editText)
                        .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String task = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
                                insertDay(task);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", null)
                        .create();
                dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations=R.style.DialogAnimation;
                dialog.show();


        }

    }
    //TEMPORARY SOLUTION
    public void insertDay(String task) {

        DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN_DAYS,task );
        db.insertWithOnConflict(ChallengesEntry.DB_TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();

    }

    public void insertTask(){

        String name=editChallengeName.getText().toString().trim();
        DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN,name);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(ChallengesEntry.DB_TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CREATE TABLE` statement does not include `NOT NULL` for the column `TaskName`, although you say that it is defined as `NOT NULL`. 
So this is the 1st inconsistency. 
You must change this line:

```
+ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN + " TEXT , "
```

to

```
+ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
```

then uninstall the app from the emulator/device so the db is deleted 
and then rerun the app so the db and the table is recreated as it is supposed to be.  
But there is a case that **the table is already created** with `NOT NULL` for the column `TaskName` and maybe you made changes to your code that don't reflect the real state of the table.  
If this is the case then **there is a reason for the error you get**: 
You have 2 different methods:
`insertTask()` and `insertDay()` to insert data to your table! **Why?** 
This means that every row of your table will have an ID and only 1 column with data, 
the other will be empty (`null`). 
Is this what you want? I don't think so. 
So if the column `TaskName` is defined `NOT NULL` and you execute `insertDay()`, 
then you get the error because `TaskName` in that row has no value (it is null) 
**and this is not allowed**. 
So get the data from the `EditText` and the `AlertDialog` 
and save it to the table with 1 insert statement, like this:

```
public boolean insertData(String taskName, String days){
    DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN,taskName);
    values.put(ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN_DAYS,days);
    boolean result = db.insert(ChallengesEntry.DB_TABLE, null, values) >= 0;
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

This method returns `true` or `false` if the insertion is successful. 
You can call it like this:

```
boolean successful = insertData(taskName, days);
```

where `taskname` and `days` are the values you collected from the `EditText` and the `AlertDialog`.
**Edit**
Declare this variable in your activity class:

```
long taskId = 0;
```

This method will insert the taskname:

```
private long insertTask(){
    String name = editChallengeName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (name.isEmpty())
        return -1;
    DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN, name);
    long id = db.insert(ChallengesEntry.DB_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

you call it where you had `insertTask();`:

```
taskid = insertTask();
```

then this method will update the row with id = taskid:

```
private void insertDay(String task) {
    DbHelper mDbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN_DAYS, task );
    db.update(ChallengesEntry.DB_TABLE, values, ChallengesEntry.DB_COLUMN + "=" + taskid, null);
    db.close();
}
```

and you call it just like you called the previous `insertDay()`

Comment: Actually you uderstood my problem properly,thanks for reply with such abstract answer.One thing i want to tell you that i actually had NOT NULL in my Column task but i don't how come i changed it,probably when debugging.Now i'll try and reply back you.Thanks

Comment: i have one doubt ,where and how do i call this method,i'm not able to understand it because my solution saves the taskName data fetched from editText which is located innside the onCreate method and i call a method insertData(); inside the menubar which stores the data with 1 column of taskname and other day column is stored using alertDialog which appears when a button is pressed.So now how do i call your prescribed methods.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have created a table in which each row has an id and 2 columns of data. Your code adds rows with only 1 column of data filled. If these 2 columns are not related to each other then you should create 2 tables: the 1st containing the taskname and the other the days. I don't know what are your needs but it seems strange that you add data to the table the way you do. I suggested to use 1 insert method if you want to have just 1 table and call it when you have a row to add, meaning you have a taskname from the EditText and days from the AlertDialog and then do as in the last line of my answer.

Comment: Are taskname and days related at all? If yes then you must insert both values to 1 row in the table. If no then you need 2 different tables.

Comment: I understand your answer clearly and also appreciate ,i did thought of creating two tables but why to create  unnecessary tables.So what i'm saying is i have one editText called editChallengeName i get that text and save through menu inflater under the column taskname and one button which when pressed opens alert dialog box with one more editText called days and save under the column days.Now how could i pass this argumets to your method which inisertData(String,String) where i could pass only either of the arguments. Please help me over here.

Comment: You can call this method when you have both values. Say the user typed something in `editChallengeName`  and then opens the AlertDialog and writes something to its EditText. When the user closes yje AlertDialog, store whatever was in that EditText in a string say `str`. Now you call `insertData(editChallengeName.getText().toString().trim(), str);`

Comment: It is not required to add the alert dialog editext.It's not NOT NULL type it can contain null.So i cannot force user too enter data in alert dialog edit text. In that case i need to create two tables,should I?

Comment: If yes,then could i use one  table row id to communicate between the two tables

Comment: This is the common practice. But you have to get the id from the 1st table to store it in the 2nd table as a foreign key.

Comment: I want like the data entered into the row of table 2 with id should be the same row in the first table with same id.Like if i entered a data in 1st table with id 1 which is auto incremented in this table and i want 2nd table data to be stored in the same id.  "So i get the same row for both". By the use of foreign key could i achieve??

Comment: In the 2nd table you would not have auto increment id. The id will be the value of the id of the 1st table. But if this is the case you could do it with 1 table: add taskname to the table first, get its id and later **update** the row with that id with days.

Comment: If i do this ,wouldn't i get the same NULL error?Becasuse i would again using the two methods which ultimately lands me to the same erro.Right?

Comment: First you must insert the taskname which is defined as not null, get the id and then update with days.

Comment: using your method?? insertData(String,String).I didn't understood.Please help.Thanks for replying.

Comment: There are 3 different things here: 2 tables, 1 table and insert both values at the same time and 1 table and insert taskname get the id and update with days. You must decide what you want because this does not lead anywhere.

Comment: 1 table and insertTaskname get the id and update with days.how do i  achieve.Could you provide me a solutioin.Mainly how do i update with days?

Comment: The edited method would have worked but for different scenario,i get again NULL in COLUMN_DAYS. Thanks for your effort but if you cold do one more help for tables using foreign key it would be great for me.Anyway gonna upvote your answer bubt please do this last help.

Comment: It seems that the code you posted  is not the code that created the table. If you get NULL in COLUMN_DAYS then uninstall the app and rerun with code that does not define  COLUMN_DAYS as NOT NULL.

Comment: I've approached the 2 tables method and also created.Please provide a solution for that.

Comment: The question in this post has nothing to do anymore with your problem. Post another question where you explain **clearly** what you need. The comments section is not the place to provide answers and it is already too long.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176289/how-to-join-two-tables-and-get-the-data-from-sqlite-database-in-one-activty-in-a